# React-Router v4 and Redux authentication

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm using react-router v4 and Redux for a new project.

I have the following code:

```
export class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(initAuth());
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <NavContainer />
          <Match pattern="/login" component={LogInForm} />
          <MatchWhenAuthorized pattern='/users' component={Users} user={user} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Where initAuth dispatches an action that checks if there's an existing token in localStorage and if there is, a logIn action is dispatched as well.

The problem is that if I go directly to `myapp.com/users` the action hasn't returned yet, so there's no user logged in and in that case MatchWhenAuthorized redirects me to my LogInForm, which I don't want if my initAuth logs a user in.

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

I think I could solve it by rendering the `MatchWhenAuthorized` component only if there's a user logged in, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Have you tried dispatching your initAuth in `componentWillMount`?

Comment: @vwrobel I did, there's no difference on the first render the user isn't set already so it doesn't Match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial login state should be set when the page is loaded and before you mount your app. I'm not sure why the `initAuth` is a redux action creator when you could just check the `localStorage` without involving redux.

### index.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducer'
import { getUser } from './storage'

// load the user data from localStorage and
// use the value in the store's initial data
const store = createStore(reducer, {
  user: getUser()
})
```

Then you can connect your `<MatchWhenAuthorized>` component to the store to access the `user` value and redirect if there is no user in the store.